# Relationships via Email Rather Than User List

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, invite, organic-groups

I'm new at Drupal, so I may have missed a solution despite a lot of research: I want users to be able to invite non-users *and* other users into a named relationship they've set up (using e.g. the Friendlist or User Relationships module) using *only* email addresses and *not* the user list. I believe that invitations from both of those modules are done only after the inviter selects the invitee after selecting the invitee from a list of all users. Frankly, I would be surprised if no email solution exists since a large site's user list would be daunting. Does anyone know if this is possible using Organic Groups? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Invite module at http://drupal.org/project/invite and turn on the User Relationships Invite plugin. Now, you will have a Relationship field in your invite form and you can invite by email.